# When is the convolution of a product the product of convolutions?

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, sobolev-spaces

Although the convolution of the product is not the product of the convolution, i.e. $$fg*h\neq (f*h)(g*h).$$

I am wondering if  this true (for a suitable class of functions) in the limit when one uses a delta net.

A delta net is defined as:

A net $\{(\varphi_{n})\}\in(0,1]$ of smooth functions on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is called a  delta net, if

- $supp( \varphi_{n})\rightarrow {0}$ as $n\rightarrow 0$
- $\int\varphi_{n} d\mu\rightarrow $ 1 as $n\rightarrow 0$
- $\varphi_{n}$ is uniformly bounded in $L^{1}(\Omega,\mu)$

For example if we consider  the convolution of $f*\varphi_{n}=f_{n}$ where $f$ is in $L_{loc}^{p}$ and if $g*\varphi_{n}=g_{n}$ is uniformly bounded then:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow 0}||f_{n}g_{n}-fg||_{p_{loc}}\rightarrow 0$$
Of course using the properties of convolutions one also has that:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow 0}||(fg)*\varphi_{n}-fg||_{p_{loc}}\rightarrow 0$$

I am wondering if anyone ones similar results for $L^{p}$ convergence, measure convergence, pointwise convergece, etc with different assumptions for $f$ and $g$.

Comment: Can you state precisely what you hope to be true?

Comment: Sorry about that. I have fixed the question now.